# Why Wordpress plugin url ajax doesn't work?

Tags: plugins, ajax, urls, wp-filesystem, plugins-url

I need to send information to the plugin folder via ajax. Wordpress has a function for the link "plugin_dir_url (__ FILE__)" which works properly but if I put it in ajax it doesn't work.

Function: **plugin_dir_url (__ FILE__)**  =  http: // localhost / aa / wp-content / plugins / pluginfolder /

This works normally:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/aa/wp-content/plugins/pluginfolder/wp-getinfo.php?"&SENDINFO=sendinfo, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
```

This does not work (php inside url):

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", ""+<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .?>+" wp-save.php?"&SENDINFO=sendinfo, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
```

This does not work (php url as variable):

```
var urlwp = <?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'wp-getinfo.php?' ?>;

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", ""+urlwp+"&SENDINFO=sendinfo, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Assuming the PHP is getting executed (i.e. this is in a .php file not a .js file) then the PHP substitutions will happen inline, meaning you'd have to quote the output as strings in JavaScript itself so that they end up as strings. (You should also escape the value you're echoing for a JavaScript string.) Have you tried looking at the result in View Source? Hopefully it should be obvious what's happening.

Comment: In View Source php code prints url, but still doesn't work, I don't know why, what needs to be changed in the code, can it help?